# How can I make sense of solidity-coverage reports

Tags: truffle, truffle-test, openzeppelin

I'm trying to check the coverage of an entire ERC20 set of openzeppelin tests. I'm using openzeppelin/test-environment and solidity-coverage v0.7.4 as plugins in truffle. The tests went fine but I get odd results for coverage.

```
Contract      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines |Uncovered Lines
Context.sol   | 0       | 100      | 0       | 0       | 20,24,25       |
ERC20.sol     | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0       |... 217,227,228 |
ERC20Mock.sol | 0       | 100      | 0       | 0       |... 16,20,24,28 |
IERC20.sol    | 100     | 100      | 100     | 100     |                |
SafeMath.sol  | 0       | 0        | 0       | 0       |... 136,153,154 |
```

As you can see, only IERC20 got entirely covered, and ERC20 got nothing despite of this contract being the implementation of the IERC20 itself. SafeMath should have some coverage as well. Does anyone can explain this? This is my first time using solidity-coverage, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you please explain the steps to get this coverage? i am not able get it and it is giving me errors

Answer (score 0):

When `solidity-coverage` completes, a folder named `coverage` is created next to the `contracts` folder (located inside your project folder).

Inside the `coverage` folder, there is a file named `index.html`, which you can open in a browser and find the coverage report depicted in a very descriptive format.

Comment: I have the same information there as the one I posted here! No use on that one as well

Comment: @honeybadger: Yes, but you can click on each one of your files and folders on the left side of the table, and a detailed report for that file or folder will be rendered in your browser.

Comment: @honeybadger: Please acknowledge.

Comment: That is correct, but it shows the red color in each statement/branch for each contract files. All except the IERC20.sol. That is the problem. According to the coverage there are no other files covered but this one

Comment: Please have a look at this [repo](https://github.com/celioggr/coverage-testing) that has the project being tested

Comment: @honeybadger: How is that helpful? You don't have the `coverage` folder stored in that repo.

Comment: @honeybadger: And regarding your "red" results - they imply that you are not covering anything in your tests. You have not included them (or any of your code for that matter) in this question, so it's a little impossible for me to refer to this problem. And in any case, your question was about reading SC report, not on how to improve the actual coverage (which requires more specific context). So I suggest that if you need help with this (improving your coverage), then you post it as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the report. It is uploaded now. 
The issue might be related with [this](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-environment/issues/21).
This is not a question of improving coverage. This is a question to understand if the results make sense for whatever reason.